# How to use create-react-app with a backend which serves index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bundle, create-react-app

I have a backend API server which is running on `https://localhost:8080`

And the frontend which is running on `https://localhost:3000`

On the backend I have a `/` route that serves an `index.html` file.

What I'm looking to accomplish is have this set up such that while I'm coding the frontend with `npm start` I receive the benefits of create-react-app's live reloading.

The issue though is that the index.html file looks like this when in debug mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src='%PUBLIC_URL%/js/axios.min.js'></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <title>My App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It's a bit better when I build the app with `npm run build` with `PUBLIC_URL=https://localhost:3000` in the `.env` file, but even then because the server isn't running then the files can't be referenced (also I rather not have to manually run that command between every change)

Is this out of scope for create-react-app? I'm not sure the proper bundling setup to use such that I use create-react-app, but instead of hosting the index.html file from the frontend, to instead serve it from the backend (this is so I can do templating on it).

Comment: What exactly is the problem? If you want live reloading in development, use `npm start` and go to `localhost:3000`, when you want to serve your app in production, run `npm run build` and then go to `localhost:8000`.

Comment: To deploy your application, follow instructions in the official documentation - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment... by the way, what do you mean by doing "templating on it"?

Comment: @HenryWoody I can't go to localhost:3000 though because that won't serve the `index.html` from my backend.

Comment: Your `index.html` should be on the frontend, going to localhost:3000 should load it in the browser, then react is loaded into `<div id="root"></div>` and from React you make calls to the backend, usually the backend just returns json data that is consumed by react

Comment: @James That's exactly the issue though. I don't want to serve the same `index.html` every time (which is why it needs to be served from the backend). For example, I want to edit the HTML contents of `index.html` from the backend and then serve a different response to each user.

Comment: That sounds like you want a classic web app, not a SPA.

Comment: @RyanPeschel this is not going to work the way you're thinking - with `CRA`, you create an `SPA` which has everything you need in there. Then you'd run `npm run build`, generate production-ready static files, and serve a single `index.html` for a `React` app from your backend. You will not be able to do templating with this setup if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: @RyanPeschel If you want do to a "different response to each user," you should look into authentication techniques with `React` and make API calls to your backend from your `React` application to serve relevant data for each user.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've already completed the app though and it is an SPA which works perfectly. The _only_ thing I want to change though is that I want to refactor it such that the initial request for the `index.html` is from the backend and is prefilled with values specific to that user (think templating)

Comment: @RyanPeschel templating won't work in this setup.

Comment: @RyanPeschel that seems like something you should be able to achieve using React rather than with templating.

Comment: @goto1: I am doing that for the majority of my application. But in this case the initial request for index.html should _also_ be from the backend so that it can avoid the "loading flicker" upon first load and also simplify my deployment (no static site hosting or route delegation needed)

Comment: @goto1: Well yeah, I'm asking for how to accomplish this setup. If create-react-app won't work, then what is the best alternative? If I have to use a separate bundler then so be it. I just assumed the CRA would support this functionality.

Comment: In that case you might be looking for "server side rendering", but you'll need to run Node in production for that not just serve static HTML/JS/CSS.

Comment: @RyanPeschel templating won't work if that's what you're thinking. If you want to avoid the "loading flicker" then you can look into "server-side rendering" to speed up your initial load, but again, you wont be able to accomplish "templating" with this setup or an SPA in general.

Comment: Okay perhaps I was using the word "templating" wrong. Yeah, the initial page load should be server side rendered. Everything else is a single page application. Is this out of scope for create-react-app? If so, which tool can accomplish this?

Comment: @RyanPeschel it depends on your setup, but the "server-side rendering" I am talking about still won't allow you to render the initial view with "prefilled values specific to a user." Depending on your setup the "server-side rendering" might look different. Have a look at https://alligator.io/react/server-side-rendering/ and https://flaviocopes.com/react-server-side-rendering/ and https://nextjs.org, but that'd be a quite different approach than what you currently have.

Comment: @goto1 I don't understand how this is impossible. What's stopping the server from just doing something like: return `"<html>{rand(0, 5)}</html>";` on the `index.html`?

Comment: Can you serve your react app from `localhost:3000/foobar` instead? Then you can keep `/` outside of your react app, do your thing there then redirect to `/foobar` with the right index.html

Comment: @RyanPeschel absolutely nothing, but **again**, an app generated by `create-react-app`, which is an SPA, is **not** meant to be used in this way. When you run `npm run build`, you get a single `index.html` file that is not meant to be edited by your backend server. If you want to serve different views/data for different users, then you need to implement authentication for your SPA.

Comment: It's possible, you'll need some server side logic - a separate app - that returns the right index.html, but you'll have to recreate this setup locally too

Comment: @James you're suggesting generating N amount of `React` apps/builds for each individual user and serving them from different paths?

Comment: @goto1 No just a way to hit a url that will allow the server to decide what will be different in the `index.html` then redirect to a new page, with that customised version, `/app` would be a better suggestion. Every user would hit `/app`

Comment: @James I don't think we're on the same page. From my understanding, OP is asking for a solution similar to `Laravel Blade` or `Node.js EJS` templates. This is **not possible** with the setup that he currently has and it's not something that you normally would do with `React` anyway.

Answer (score -3):

You don't use a backend with React in this way.

React is UI framework for simplifying the Front end development.

Server API's are used to interface with databases and retrieve & store data and also for hosting the routes used to make POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE etc. requests. You can use Template rendering engines on the back end to render and serve HTML pages statically with some dynamically loaded content via template deconstructors, however As far as  i know this isn't compatible with the way react operates.  Typically the backend used with a react front end would be used to interface btwn the database and the react components state.

It sounds like what you need to do to achieve what you want is convert your static html page into JSX and render it through a react component and use a backend (if you still need one) to pass any data that is needed for the page, Or you can create a pure server based web application which uses template engines to serve static html pages.

If you do need to send data from your server to the front end you should also update your package.json file to include a proxy with the address of the api

`"proxy": "http://localhost:8000/",`